# Find if path exists in a matrix using DFS?

Tags: algorithm, graph

The problem is given an `mxn` matrix of 1 and 0, where 1 is obstacle and 0 is allowed vertex, find if a path exists from top left to bottom right of the matrix using DFS. You can move up down left or right.

Notice it doesn't ask for shortest path, this problem has actually surprisingly tripped me up. I can do this quite easily with BFS, but the DFS aspect is confusing, moreover whats confusing with DFS is that, it is supposedly faster in the best case as it doesnt explore all possible paths like BFS.

But if we are doing DFS, wont we be doing backtracking as this is an **undirected** graph so we cant do DFS directly? From my understanding this blows up the time complexity to `O(4^n)`, which is significantly slower than BFS.

```
public boolean pathExists(int[][] matrix){
  boolean [][] used = new boolean[matrix.length][matrix[0].length];

}

public boolean pathExistsHelper(int [][] matrix, int vertexRow, int vertexCol, boolean [][] used){
    if(outOfbounds(...) return false;
    if(used[vertexRow][vertexCol]) return false;

     used[vertexRow][vertexCol] = true;
     for(each direction) if(pathExists...) return true
     used[vertexRow][vertexCol] = false; // backtrack
    
    return false;
}
```

So you can see what I mean, I was told DFS is equally as fast, but how is it possible to do DFS on an undirected graph without backtracking into exponential complexity? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to unmark vertices - because your goal is not to enumerate *all possible non-self-intersecting paths*, of which there are indeed many. This reduces the run-time complexity to O(n), where n is the number of vertices; the same complexity as in BFS, but without needing to store as many vertices in memory, since you do not need a queue.

This kind of DFS is very common to find connected components in graphs, and is also referred to as "flood fill".

A simpler code could look like this:

```
public boolean pathExists(int[][] matrix) {
     boolean exitFound = pathExists(m, 0, 0);
     // replace 2s by 0s to undo changes to matrix here
     // ...
     return exitFound;
}

public boolean pathExists(int[][] m, int row, int col) {
     // base cases         
     if (row < 0 || col < 0 || row >= m.length || col >= m[0].length) 
        return false; // out-of-bounds
     if (m[row][col] != 0)
        return false; // avoid visiting walls or re-visiting
     if (row == m.length-1 && col == m[0].length-1)
        return true;  // success!

     // mark & prepare for recursion
     m[row][col] = 2; // never visit again; replace 2s by 0s to undo changes
     return pathExists(m, row+1, col) ||
            pathExists(m, row-1, col) ||
            pathExists(m, row, col+1) ||
            pathExists(m, row, col-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general DFS cannot be applied without additions to an undirected graph because it cannot handle cycles. So you must at least add cycle-detection to avoid to run around a cycle for ever.

In you case you need to avoid to leave a matrix-position in the same direction as you already did before in your path (this would lead to a cycle and you'll never find a solution).

---

**About the speed of DFS and BFS:**
In worst case they both need to search the whole stat-tree of the problem and both search every node just once so the they are equally fast (in worst case).